# Optimally Find Empty Space On Grid

Tags: optimization, logic, spacing, packing

I'm hoping somebody can help me optimize an algorithm I'm dealing with in my current project.  This is being coded in C#, but is more of a logic problem.

I have a two-dimensional array of bools (a grid) which act as a container of rectangles.  When a rectangle is placed on the grid, it toggles the bools to true.

Empty space = false

Occupied space = true

Now for the problem.  How do I find the closest empty position to a point (x, y) where a rectangle of width (w) and height (h) can fit without overlapping an occupied space?

I've done a very naive baseline implementation that works as follows:

```
WHILE point not found
  SET g to nearest unchecked grid point
  SET allempty to true

  FOR EACH x value in rect (i)
     FOR EACH y value in rect (j)
       IF gridpoint[i, j] is occupied
          SET allempty to false;
       END IF
     END FOR
  END FOR

  IF allempty
     RETURN g as legal location
  END IF
END WHILE
```

But I know there are other, more efficient ways to perform this operation.  Can anybody point me to an algorithm that could do this more effectively?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Do you have to only use that grid or can you use additional data structures?

Comment: Additional data structures would be fine as long as it's performant.  This is for a real project that I'm the sole programmer on.  Pretty much anything goes if it helps optimize things.